# generate combinations from hash values

Tags: perl, hash

In perl if I have a hash

```
my %ranges = (                                                                                      
'--tic' => [ 0, 1, 2 ],                                                                             
'--threads' => [ 8, 16 ],                                                                           
'--level' => [ 10, 20 ]                                                                               
);
```

how can I generate an array of all the combinations, like

```
--level 10 --threads 8 --tic 0                                                                        
--level 10 --threads 8 --tic 1                                                                        
--level 10 --threads 8 --tic 2                                                                        
--level 10 --threads 16 --tic 0                                                                       
--level 10 --threads 16 --tic 1                                                                       
--level 10 --threads 16 --tic 2                                                                       
--level 20 --threads 8 --tic 0                                                                        
--level 20 --threads 8 --tic 1                                                                        
--level 20 --threads 8 --tic 2                                                                        
--level 20 --threads 16 --tic 0                                                                       
--level 20 --threads 16 --tic 1                                                                       
--level 20 --threads 16 --tic 2
```

There can be any number of hash entries, and each entry can have any number of elements in it's value array. The order of the output array doesn't matter, just needs to have 1 element for each combination, 3*2*2 = 12 in this case, but could be any number.

I think some combination of splice, map, and foreach should work but I am flailing about in a bad way to find it.

Comment: You're trying to generate what's called the Cartesian product (or cross product); there are several modules on CPAN that can help with this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As already mentioned, you're looking for [Cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product),

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub getCartesian {
#
  my @input = @_;
  my @ret = map [$_], @{ shift @input };

  for my $a2 (@input) {
    @ret = map {
      my $v = $_;
      map [@$v, $_], @$a2;
    }
    @ret;
  }
  return @ret;
}

my %ranges = (
    '--tic' => [ 0, 1, 2 ],
    '--threads' => [ 8, 16 ],
    '--level' => [ 10, 20 ]
);

my @arr =  map {
  my $k = $_;
  [ map "$k $_", @{$ranges{$k}} ];
}
keys %ranges;

print "@$_\n" for getCartesian(@arr);
```

output

```
--level 10 --tic 0 --threads 8
--level 10 --tic 0 --threads 16
--level 10 --tic 1 --threads 8
--level 10 --tic 1 --threads 16
--level 10 --tic 2 --threads 8
--level 10 --tic 2 --threads 16
--level 20 --tic 0 --threads 8
--level 20 --tic 0 --threads 16
--level 20 --tic 1 --threads 8
--level 20 --tic 1 --threads 16
--level 20 --tic 2 --threads 8
--level 20 --tic 2 --threads 16
```

Answer (score 4):

The [`Set::Product`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Set::Product) module will do this for you

Here's an example program

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Set::Product 'product';

my %ranges = (
    '--tic'     => [ 0, 1, 2 ],
    '--threads' => [ 8, 16 ],
    '--level'   => [ 10, 20 ],
);

my @keys = sort keys %ranges;

product {
    print join(' ', map { "$keys[$_] $_[$_]" } 0 .. $#keys), "\n";
} @ranges{@keys};
```

#### output

```
--level 10 --threads 8 --tic 0
--level 10 --threads 8 --tic 1
--level 10 --threads 8 --tic 2
--level 10 --threads 16 --tic 0
--level 10 --threads 16 --tic 1
--level 10 --threads 16 --tic 2
--level 20 --threads 8 --tic 0
--level 20 --threads 8 --tic 1
--level 20 --threads 8 --tic 2
--level 20 --threads 16 --tic 0
--level 20 --threads 16 --tic 1
--level 20 --threads 16 --tic 2
```